# 8 - Views ignores my "Grouping field"

Tags: views, 8

I'm relearning views with D8 and am converting some old D6 views. I've created a view with "Grouping field" set in "Style options", but the SQL generated doesn't include any GROUP BY field.

The field in question is a date, which I am custom formatting as "Y" and have ticked "Use rendered output to group rows".

The SQL generated is:

```
SELECT node_field_data.langcode AS node_field_data_langcode, node_field_data.title AS node_field_data_title, node_field_data.nid AS nid, DATE_FORMAT(node__field_publication_date.field_publication_date_value, '%Y') AS node__field_publication_date_field_publication_date_value_ye
FROM 
{node_field_data} node_field_data
INNER JOIN {node__library_type} node__library_type ON node_field_data.nid = node__library_type.entity_id AND (node__library_type.deleted = '0' AND node__library_type.langcode = node_field_data.langcode)
LEFT JOIN {node__field_publication_date} node__field_publication_date ON node_field_data.nid = node__field_publication_date.entity_id AND (node__field_publication_date.deleted = '0' AND node__field_publication_date.langcode = node_field_data.langcode)
WHERE (( (node__library_type.library_type_target_id = '1937') )AND(( (node_field_data.status = 1 OR (node_field_data.uid = 1 AND 1 <> 0 AND 1 = 1) OR 1 = 1) AND (node_field_data.type IN  ('library')) )))
ORDER BY node__field_publication_date_field_publication_date_value_ye DESC, node_field_data_title ASC
```

Is this because I'm using "Fields" mode to display?

Comment: This may or may not be the cause: https://www.drupal.org/node/2369119

Comment: It may be that Group By field operates via rendering and not on the query level. To get the Group By you can add Aggregate option. And the output is correct, you just don;t see the Group By clause, correct?

Comment: @J.Reynolds the default twig template isn't showing anything but maybe it's a problem there rather than the Virews module - will check it out!